# copying local source code to jenkins Workspace

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber, workspace

I want to set up a small cucumber (maven) project in Jenkins in my company. The source code is local on my machine and not on any subversion system. I have already created a new job in jenkins. While configuring I am asked to give path to my pom.xml. But I dont know how do I give path.
Also I triggered Jenkins build without even configuring it properly, and therefore it has generated Workspace (Arbeitsbereich in german) for me. Now I think I just need to copy my source code to the created Workspace, but I dont know how do I do that exactly.
May be I am doing something really dumb here :( could someone please help ?
[image]

Comment: For local code, there is no proper workspace folder on Jenkins, as u are not using any subvesrion. first, correct your configuration. As it local project you can give path directly. eg. C:\project_path\pom.xml

Comment: I tried that already, giving absolute path to my pom.xml. But it seems that its not finding it. It says Pom.xml does not exist in specified path, although it is there.

Comment: Yes Atul N. I am able to do "dir C:\Users\Rag\workspace\cucumberJunit_CalculatorExample\pom.xml" and also able to run "mvn clean install" in my project folder

Comment: try same command preceding will `call` or `bat  'dir C:\\Users\\Rag\\workspace\\cucumberJunit_CalculatorExample\\pom.x‌ml'`. looks like some configuration issue. I am considering you are running this  in **Build -> Execute Windows batch Command** and there is no space in between directory or file path

Comment: i am specifying absolute path in Build section Root-POM field (C:\Users\Rag\workspace\cucumberJunit_CalculatorExample) and in field Goals and Options "clean install". I hope i m doing it right !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151585/discussion-between-atul-n-and-ragini).

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins default directory would be '~/.jenkins' where your jobs should be located. you can follow [this link](http://ingorichter.blogspot.com.eg/2012/02/jenkins-change-workspaces-and-build.html) to use a custom directory as your work space.

After that, you can specify the path of your application pom.xml file relatively to your custom workspace location.

Comment: Do u mean Jenkins creates directory ~/.jenkins would be on my local machine ?

Comment: I also tried by specifying custom path (C:/Users/Rag/workspace) and then specifying pom.xml path (CucumberJunit_CalculatorExample). but it gives me IO Exception Failed to mkdirs: C:/Users/Rag/workspace

Comment: Do you've Jenkins installed on the same machine that has your application files (I mean your project files)?

Comment: Amr Afifi, that's what I also doubt about. The jenkins is on our company server and My sample project is on my local machine. Could this be a problem ?